# Test First Ruby Dictionary Add method

Tags: ruby, class, hash, arguments

I'm new to ruby

@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
@d.find('fish').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}

but how can you take => as a argument? How can I take the argument 'fish'=>'aquatic animal' and set the instance variable @entries[fish] = aquatic animal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Class could just looks like this:

```
class Dictionary

  def new
    @entries = {}
  end

  def add(hash = {})
    hash.each do |key, value| 
      @entries.update(key => value)    # or `@entries[key] = value`
    end
  end

  def find(key)
    value = @entries[key]
    { key => value } if value
  end

end
```

Comment: I still get an error when only 'fish' is entered. I figured a way to allow both 'fish' => 'aquatic animal' and just 'fish' by using a variable length argument aka add(*arg)